# Сигнал setText label qt

Tags: qt, c++

Попытке соединения слота и сигнала предшествует простой код:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget   window;
    window.setWindowTitle("test");

    QLabel *label = new QLabel("hello world");
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("start", &window);
...//тут обжект::коннект
```

Попытка номер один:

```
QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), label, SLOT(setText("teststring")));
//код ярко отображает, что я хочу сделать: передать слоту аргумент отличный от сигнала, но так просто этого не сделать :(
```

Попытка номер два, используя лябмду:

```
QObject::connect(button, &button::clicked, [=](){label->setText("test");});
//Ошибка: "'button' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration" - оно конечно понятно, что вторым аргументом должен быть класс, но подсунув туда &QPushButton тоже ловлю ошибку 'void QAbstractButton::clicked(bool)' is protected.
```

Попытка номер 3. Если у слота и сигнала должны быть одинаковые аргументы, значит надо расширить класс label еще одним слотом, который бы не принимал аргументы и ставил текст, примерно так:

```
QLabel::convertionSlot()
{
    label->setText("some text");
}
```

Но поскольку я хеловордящее чудо, то я забыл, что прежде функцию `convertionSlot` надо объявить в классе. И, в общем, править исходники это не мой путь. :(

Мне нужна помощь. Как реализовать попытку два и три прямыми руками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попытка №2 - проблема может быть в компиляторе, а не в коде. У меня вполне себе сработало

QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, ={label->setText("test");});

но только после того, как я добавил `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++11` (поддержку с++11) в про файл. То, что у вас та же строка нужна, не уверен, это уже зависит от того, что за компилятор используется, у меня винда с 32 битным мингв 4.8.2 , точно помню, что на маке с его клангом была другая строка.

Попытка №3 - так делать можно в obj-с (там это категория называется), но вроде не в c++. Для c++ есть следующие варианты:

1. Сделать своего наследника от QLabel и у него определить данный слот, только тогда надо писать не `label->setText("some text");`, а `this->setText("some text");` или просто `setText("some text");`, поскольку label - это объект в нашей программе, и сам класс про него, естественно, ничего не знает и не должен.
2. Сделать меняющий текст слот у окна (все равно почти всегда приходится делать его наследника) и дергать его.