# Передача параметров в слот

Tags: qt, c++

Всем доброго времени суток.

Никак не могу найти хорошей простой реализации для данной задачи. В поле `QLineEdit` вводится определенный текст. Затем после нажатия кнопки `QPushButton` нужно, чтобы вызвался определенный слот с параметром `QLineEdit::text`. Подскажите, как это можно выполнить?

Такой способ, к сожалению, не подходит:

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, some_slot(lineedit->text));
```

Буду премного благодарен тому, кто сможет дать полноценный вразумительный ответ. 
Спасибо!

Comment: @Антон Вахрушев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Создайте дополнительный слот без параметров и подключите к нему кнопку, а внутри вызывайте уже необходимый слот как простую функцию:

```
some_slot(lineedit->text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Буквально месяц назад обсуждали [Сигнал setText label qt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/372956/c-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-settext-label-qt)